# Is it possible to add onprem_sid claim to AAD Identity Token obtained via AAD v2 endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, claims, azure-ad-msal

I've got a SPA application that uses MSAL to obtain an identity token for a user authenticating against our AAD.  We have a one-way sync from our on-prem AD to our AAD and the on-prem SID is stored in the AAD.

When I was using ADAL to obtain a token, I actually received the on-prem SID as part of the identity token; however, that changed when switching to MSAL.

I'm curious if there is some way to add the on-prem SID claim to the token returned from the v2 endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK , Azure AD V2.0 doesn't support to issue the custom claim at present. You can send feature request to [Azure AD Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .

Comment: is this still the case?  It seems that AAD now supports a "optionalClaims" collection, is that what this is intended for?